# Random Smart Car Data Generator

Tags: java

I am trying to generate random sets of data in my current code. I have read samples of data on how to create random item selections but none will show me how to add multiple list of items to generate the random print lines for all of the items at once.

I have looked at references in random items from list. But most only show one item. I have looked at geeks for geeks in their Random sample using integers, but I need to generate more than just integers, also string selections from the items.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.Random;

public class SmartCarDataGenerator
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
/*
Author
System
Subsystem
Methodology
Driver behavior detection

GDi
Lpi
Variable 
Sensor data
Defenition

GDi_Speed
GDi_RPM
GDi_Ignitor_sensor
GDi_MAP_sensor
GDi_Front_oxygen_sensor
GDi_Injection_Time_Sensor_1
GDi_Fuel_rail_pressure_sensor
GDi_Knock_sensor_1
GDi_Knock_sensor_2
GDi_Knock_sensor_3
GDi_Knock_sensor_4
GDi_Speed

LPi_Speed
LPi_RPM
LPi_Ignitor_sensor
LPi_MAP_sensor
LPi_Front_oxygen_sensor
LPi_Injection_Time_Sensor_1
LPi_Fuel_rail_pressure_sensor
LPi_Knock_sensor_1
LPi_Knock_sensor_2
LPi_Knock_sensor_3
LPi_Knock_sensor_4
Lpi_Speed

N
Mean
SD
Min
Max

GDi_Variable
GDi_Coeffifient
GDi_pValue
GDi_Result

LPi_Variable
LPi_Coeffifient
LPi_pValue
LPi_Result

*/

    Random rand = new Random();

    List<String> author = new ArrayList<String>();
    author.add("Beatrice");
    author.add("Wang");
    author.add("Luo");
    author.add("Han");
    author.add("Cesar");
    author.add("Zhang");
    author.add("Hu");
    author.add("Lee");
    author.add("Chung");

    List<String> system = new ArrayList<String>();
    system.add("Engine");
    system.add("Battery");
    system.add("Steering");
    system.add("Brakes");
    system.add("Suspension");
    system.add("Muffler");
    system.add("FanRadiator");
    system.add("Radiator");
    system.add("AirConditinor");
    system.add("SoundSystem");

    List<String> subsystem = new ArrayList<String>();
    subsystem.add("OBD");
    subsystem.add("CVDP");
    subsystem.add("BGA");
    subsystem.add("EPSG");
    subsystem.add("LithiumBattery");
    subsystem.add("ElectricPowerSteering");
    subsystem.add("AntiLockBrakes");
    subsystem.add("suspension");

    List<String> methodology = new ArrayList<String>();
    methodology.add("DataDriven");
    methodology.add("ModelBased");

    List<String> driverBehaviorDetection = new ArrayList<String>();
    driverBehaviorDetection.add("Fatigue");
    driverBehaviorDetection.add("Drowsiness");
    driverBehaviorDetection.add("Distraction");
    driverBehaviorDetection.add("AccelerationHabit");
    driverBehaviorDetection.add("Texting");
    driverBehaviorDetection.add("Mad");
    driverBehaviorDetection.add("Happy");
    driverBehaviorDetection.add("RoadRage");
    driverBehaviorDetection.add("MedicalCondition");

    List<String> variable_car_condition = new ArrayList<String>();
    variable_car_condition.add("Normal");
    variable_car_condition.add("Abnormal");

    int variable_driver_id = rand.nextInt(100000);

    List<String> speedMode = new ArrayList<String>();
    speedMode.add("Idling");
    speedMode.add("Driving");

  }

}
```

I would like to receive suggestions to how I would generate print lines that add everything of the List items I have using loop functions or a class that I call to pass 1000 of the entire Lists to generate data. I would also like to learn how to create a random selection that has more than one value from a list.

Comment: Can you show an example of what one random dataset should look like?

Comment: You say you've found how to get a random element of a list, but why can't you use the same code to get one value from each list?

Comment: `I would also like to learn how to create a random selection that has more than one value from a list.` -> Repeat the same as "select one random value" n-times to get a selection of size n

Answer (score 0):

Your driver ID line is out of place. All the other lines are setting up the domain of possible values. That ID line determines a specific choice of a value from the domain of one hundred thousand values.

Move that ID line to a new for-loop. Inside that loop you choose a particular value from each domain of possibilities. Pass the resulting choice for each kind of value to a constructor or builder of your `Car` class. Add the resulting `Car` object to a collection such as a `List` or `Set`. Then continue the loop to make-and-add another car, and another, etc.

By the way, simply generating a random number is not a proper way to assign unique identifiers. You’ll need to track used numbers to avoid duplicates, avoid assigning the same number more than once. Or create an incrementing sequential number. Or use instead a UUID. All of these have been covered many many times on Stack Overflow, so search for more info.

Comment: Hi all, the next question is how do I code for multiple random items for one or more than one response from the Lists?

Comment: @CesarMojarro I cannot understand your comment.

Comment: As you can see, there are multiple selections, but only one response. I would like to randomize the amount of responses for each List, to be either one or more than one item. For example on a car you have sometimes multiple problems, so I want to code a method that would execute the response variance.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the response. It really helped me think of a structured way of generating data. For this example I will post a simple way of generating data that you made it super clear.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.Random; 

public class SmartCarDataGenerator{

public static void main(String[] args){
         /*
         Author
         System
         Subsystem
         Methodology
         Driver behavior detection

         GDi
         Lpi
         Variable 
         Sensor data
         Defenition

         GDi_Speed
         GDi_RPM
         GDi_Ignitor_sensor
         GDi_MAP_sensor
         GDi_Front_oxygen_sensor
         GDi_Injection_Time_Sensor_1
         GDi_Fuel_rail_pressure_sensor
         GDi_Knock_sensor_1
         GDi_Knock_sensor_2
         GDi_Knock_sensor_3
         GDi_Knock_sensor_4
         GDi_Speed

         LPi_Speed
         LPi_RPM
         LPi_Ignitor_sensor
         LPi_MAP_sensor
         LPi_Front_oxygen_sensor
         LPi_Injection_Time_Sensor_1
         LPi_Fuel_rail_pressure_sensor
         LPi_Knock_sensor_1
         LPi_Knock_sensor_2
         LPi_Knock_sensor_3
         LPi_Knock_sensor_4
         Lpi_Speed

         N
         Mean
         SD
         Min
         Max

         GDi_Variable
         GDi_Coeffifient
         GDi_pValue
         GDi_Result

         LPi_Variable
         LPi_Coeffifient
         LPi_pValue
         LPi_Result

         */

         Random rand = new Random(); 

         List<String> author = new ArrayList<String>();
         author.add("Beatrice");
         author.add("Wang");
         author.add("Luo");
         author.add("Han");
         author.add("Cesar");
         author.add("Zhang");
         author.add("Hu");
         author.add("Lee");
         author.add("Chung");


         List<String> system = new ArrayList<String>();
         system.add("Engine");
         system.add("Battery");
         system.add("Steering");
         system.add("Brakes");
         system.add("Suspension");
         system.add("Muffler");
         system.add("FanRadiator");
         system.add("Radiator");
         system.add("AirConditinor");
         system.add("SoundSystem");

         List<String> subsystem = new ArrayList<String>();
         subsystem .add("OBD");
         subsystem .add("CVDP");
         subsystem .add("BGA");
         subsystem .add("EPSG");
         subsystem .add("LithiumBattery");
         subsystem .add("ElectricPowerSteering");
         subsystem .add("AntiLockBrakes");
         subsystem .add("suspension");

         List<String> methodology = new ArrayList<String>();
         methodology.add("DataDriven");
         methodology.add("ModelBased");

         List<String> driverBehaviorDetection = new ArrayList<String>();
         driverBehaviorDetection.add("Fatigue");
         driverBehaviorDetection.add("Drowsiness");
         driverBehaviorDetection.add("Distraction");
         driverBehaviorDetection.add("AccelerationHabit");
         driverBehaviorDetection.add("Texting");
         driverBehaviorDetection.add("Mad");
         driverBehaviorDetection.add("Happy");
         driverBehaviorDetection.add("RoadRage");
         driverBehaviorDetection.add("MedicalCondition");

         List<String> variable_car_condition = new ArrayList<String>();
         variable_car_condition .add("Normal");
         variable_car_condition .add("Abnormal");


         //int variable_driver_id = rand.nextInt(100000);

         List<String> speedMode = new ArrayList<String>();
         speedMode.add("Idling");
         speedMode.add("Driving");

         SmartCarDataGenerator obj = new SmartCarDataGenerator();

         for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){  
         System.out.println(obj.getRandomItem(author, system, subsystem, methodology, driverBehaviorDetection, variable_car_condition, speedMode));
         }
      }

  public String getRandomItem(List<String> author, List<String> system, List<String> subsystem, List<String> methodology, List<String> driverBehaviorDetection, List<String> variable_car_condition, List<String> speedMode){
      Random rand = new Random();
      return author.get(rand.nextInt(author.size()))+ ", " + system.get(rand.nextInt(system.size()))+ ", " + subsystem.get(rand.nextInt(subsystem.size()))+ ", " + methodology.get(rand.nextInt(methodology.size()))+ ", " + driverBehaviorDetection.get(rand.nextInt(driverBehaviorDetection.size()))+ ", " + variable_car_condition.get(rand.nextInt(variable_car_condition.size()))+ ", " + speedMode.get(rand.nextInt(speedMode.size())) ;

  }

}
```

This example allowed me to generate the sample data I can start working on:

Zhang, Muffler, ElectricPowerSteering, DataDriven, AccelerationHabit, Abnormal, Idling
Wang, SoundSystem, suspension, ModelBased, Distraction, Abnormal, Idling
Beatrice, SoundSystem, EPSG, DataDriven, Texting, Normal, Driving
Wang, FanRadiator, suspension, ModelBased, Texting, Normal, Idling
Hu, Radiator, LithiumBattery, ModelBased, Happy, Abnormal, Idling
Chung, SoundSystem, ElectricPowerSteering, DataDriven, Drowsiness, Normal, Driving
Lee, Engine, OBD, ModelBased, RoadRage, Abnormal, Driving
Cesar, Engine, EPSG, DataDriven, RoadRage, Abnormal, Idling
Beatrice, Suspension, AntiLockBrakes, ModelBased, Drowsiness, Normal, Idling
Wang, Muffler, CVDP, ModelBased, RoadRage, Abnormal, Driving
Lee, Brakes, BGA, DataDriven, Drowsiness, Abnormal, Idling
Han, Muffler, OBD, DataDriven, Happy, Abnormal, Driving
Han, Muffler, suspension, ModelBased, Distraction, Normal, Idling
Chung, Brakes, OBD, DataDriven, Fatigue, Normal, Idling
Luo, Brakes, ElectricPowerSteering, DataDriven, RoadRage, Abnormal, Driving
Cesar, Muffler, EPSG, ModelBased, RoadRage, Normal, Driving
Zhang, FanRadiator, LithiumBattery, ModelBased, AccelerationHabit, Normal, Idling
Cesar, Battery, AntiLockBrakes, ModelBased, Texting, Abnormal, Driving
Han, Suspension, BGA, ModelBased, Texting, Normal, Driving
Chung, Brakes, CVDP, ModelBased, Texting, Normal, Idling
Han, Steering, BGA, DataDriven, Distraction, Abnormal, Driving
Hu, AirConditinor, EPSG, ModelBased, Mad, Abnormal, Idling
Chung, AirConditinor, CVDP, ModelBased, Texting, Abnormal, Driving
Hu, Steering, CVDP, ModelBased, MedicalCondition, Abnormal, Idling
Beatrice, SoundSystem, ElectricPowerSteering, ModelBased, Fatigue, Normal, Idling
Luo, FanRadiator, OBD, ModelBased, Happy, Abnormal, Driving
Luo, Engine, CVDP, DataDriven, MedicalCondition, Normal, Driving
Chung, Steering, LithiumBattery, DataDriven, Mad, Abnormal, Driving
Han, AirConditinor, OBD, ModelBased, Happy, Abnormal, Idling
Wang, Suspension, CVDP, ModelBased, Distraction, Abnormal, Driving
Chung, Battery, CVDP, DataDriven, MedicalCondition, Normal, Idling
Cesar, Radiator, BGA, ModelBased, Happy, Normal, Driving
Chung, Engine, ElectricPowerSteering, DataDriven, Happy, Abnormal, Idling
Cesar, Brakes, BGA, ModelBased, MedicalCondition, Normal, Idling
Lee, Radiator, LithiumBattery, DataDriven, RoadRage, Normal, Idling
Luo, Muffler, LithiumBattery, ModelBased, Distraction, Normal, Driving
Cesar, Steering, suspension, DataDriven, AccelerationHabit, Abnormal, Driving
Cesar, Suspension, suspension, ModelBased, Drowsiness, Normal, Idling
Lee, Muffler, OBD, DataDriven, Mad, Abnormal, Driving
Lee, Steering, EPSG, DataDriven, AccelerationHabit, Normal, Driving
Wang, Engine, BGA, ModelBased, AccelerationHabit, Normal, Idling
Luo, SoundSystem, BGA, ModelBased, Fatigue, Abnormal, Driving
Beatrice, Battery, AntiLockBrakes, DataDriven, MedicalCondition, Abnormal, Driving
Zhang, Brakes, LithiumBattery, ModelBased, RoadRage, Abnormal, Idling
Beatrice, SoundSystem, suspension, DataDriven, Distraction, Normal, Idling
Chung, AirConditinor, AntiLockBrakes, ModelBased, AccelerationHabit, Normal, Idling
Cesar, Suspension, LithiumBattery, ModelBased, MedicalCondition, Normal, Idling
Lee, SoundSystem, BGA, ModelBased, RoadRage, Abnormal, Driving
Chung, Engine, AntiLockBrakes, ModelBased, Distraction, Abnormal, Driving
Chung, AirConditinor, LithiumBattery, ModelBased, Texting, Abnormal, Idling
Zhang, FanRadiator, CVDP, ModelBased, Mad, Normal, Idling
Han, Steering, AntiLockBrakes, ModelBased, Drowsiness, Normal, Idling
Cesar, Brakes, suspension, ModelBased, Drowsiness, Normal, Driving
Han, FanRadiator, LithiumBattery, ModelBased, Happy, Abnormal, Driving
Cesar, AirConditinor, suspension, DataDriven, Texting, Normal, Idling
Wang, Steering, ElectricPowerSteering, DataDriven, AccelerationHabit, Normal, Driving
Lee, AirConditinor, LithiumBattery, DataDriven, Drowsiness, Normal, Idling
Zhang, Brakes, OBD, ModelBased, Drowsiness, Normal, Idling
Wang, Engine, OBD, ModelBased, AccelerationHabit, Normal, Driving
Chung, Radiator, ElectricPowerSteering, ModelBased, Texting, Abnormal, Idling
Lee, AirConditinor, CVDP, ModelBased, AccelerationHabit, Abnormal, Idling
Lee, SoundSystem, EPSG, ModelBased, AccelerationHabit, Normal, Idling
Cesar, Brakes, ElectricPowerSteering, ModelBased, Distraction, Abnormal, Driving
Cesar, Engine, OBD, ModelBased, RoadRage, Abnormal, Driving
Cesar, SoundSystem, BGA, DataDriven, RoadRage, Abnormal, Driving
Wang, Radiator, LithiumBattery, DataDriven, RoadRage, Abnormal, Idling
Chung, Engine, CVDP, DataDriven, MedicalCondition, Abnormal, Idling
Luo, Brakes, suspension, DataDriven, Happy, Normal, Idling
Zhang, Muffler, BGA, DataDriven, Distraction, Normal, Idling
Beatrice, Battery, EPSG, DataDriven, Happy, Normal, Driving
Lee, Steering, LithiumBattery, DataDriven, Fatigue, Abnormal, Idling
Beatrice, SoundSystem, LithiumBattery, ModelBased, Distraction, Normal, Driving
Hu, Engine, CVDP, ModelBased, MedicalCondition, Normal, Driving
Zhang, Radiator, ElectricPowerSteering, DataDriven, Fatigue, Abnormal, Idling
Han, Engine, suspension, DataDriven, Happy, Normal, Driving
Beatrice, Radiator, suspension, ModelBased, Mad, Normal, Driving
Lee, Brakes, BGA, DataDriven, AccelerationHabit, Abnormal, Idling
Lee, Muffler, AntiLockBrakes, ModelBased, RoadRage, Normal, Idling
Wang, AirConditinor, CVDP, ModelBased, Distraction, Normal, Idling
Chung, FanRadiator, EPSG, ModelBased, Texting, Normal, Idling
Hu, Muffler, EPSG, ModelBased, AccelerationHabit, Abnormal, Driving
Beatrice, Suspension, LithiumBattery, ModelBased, Happy, Abnormal, Idling
Hu, Brakes, EPSG, ModelBased, Happy, Abnormal, Idling
Wang, Suspension, LithiumBattery, DataDriven, RoadRage, Abnormal, Idling
Zhang, AirConditinor, CVDP, DataDriven, MedicalCondition, Abnormal, Driving
Hu, Battery, suspension, DataDriven, Drowsiness, Abnormal, Idling
Han, Suspension, LithiumBattery, ModelBased, Distraction, Normal, Idling
Wang, Muffler, CVDP, ModelBased, Happy, Abnormal, Driving
Cesar, Engine, suspension, ModelBased, Texting, Normal, Driving
Cesar, AirConditinor, CVDP, DataDriven, Fatigue, Normal, Driving
Zhang, Engine, OBD, ModelBased, Happy, Normal, Driving
Lee, Radiator, AntiLockBrakes, DataDriven, Distraction, Normal, Driving
Cesar, SoundSystem, BGA, ModelBased, RoadRage, Normal, Idling
Lee, FanRadiator, LithiumBattery, ModelBased, AccelerationHabit, Abnormal, Idling
Lee, AirConditinor, LithiumBattery, ModelBased, Mad, Abnormal, Driving
Hu, Muffler, LithiumBattery, DataDriven, Fatigue, Abnormal, Idling
Chung, Radiator, ElectricPowerSteering, DataDriven, Texting, Abnormal, Driving
Cesar, FanRadiator, OBD, ModelBased, RoadRage, Normal, Idling
Wang, Muffler, suspension, DataDriven, Distraction, Abnormal, Idling
Lee, AirConditinor, LithiumBattery, ModelBased, Distraction, Normal, Driving
Lee, Steering, ElectricPowerSteering, ModelBased, AccelerationHabit, Abnormal, Idling
Lee, Engine, ElectricPowerSteering, DataDriven, Drowsiness, Normal, Driving
Han, Brakes, ElectricPowerSteering, ModelBased, RoadRage, Normal, Idling
Hu, Steering, CVDP, DataDriven, AccelerationHabit, Normal, Driving
Han, FanRadiator, AntiLockBrakes, ModelBased, Drowsiness, Abnormal, Driving
Chung, SoundSystem, suspension, DataDriven, AccelerationHabit, Normal, Driving
Chung, Battery, AntiLockBrakes, ModelBased, Texting, Abnormal, Driving
Beatrice, FanRadiator, LithiumBattery, DataDriven, Fatigue, Normal, Idling
Chung, SoundSystem, AntiLockBrakes, ModelBased, Happy, Normal, Driving
Beatrice, AirConditinor, BGA, DataDriven, MedicalCondition, Abnormal, Idling
Han, Suspension, EPSG, ModelBased, RoadRage, Abnormal, Idling
Lee, Brakes, LithiumBattery, ModelBased, Texting, Abnormal, Idling
Cesar, SoundSystem, CVDP, ModelBased, Drowsiness, Normal, Idling
Cesar, AirConditinor, ElectricPowerSteering, ModelBased, Fatigue, Normal, Driving
Cesar, FanRadiator, ElectricPowerSteering, ModelBased, Drowsiness, Normal, Idling
Chung, Engine, ElectricPowerSteering, ModelBased, RoadRage, Normal, Idling
Lee, Radiator, LithiumBattery, DataDriven, Drowsiness, Abnormal, Driving
Cesar, Battery, OBD, ModelBased, Fatigue, Abnormal, Driving
Hu, FanRadiator, AntiLockBrakes, DataDriven, Mad, Abnormal, Driving
Chung, Suspension, AntiLockBrakes, ModelBased, Drowsiness, Abnormal, Driving
Han, Steering, ElectricPowerSteering, DataDriven, Fatigue, Normal, Driving
Han, FanRadiator, OBD, ModelBased, Texting, Abnormal, Driving
Chung, Steering, EPSG, DataDriven, Texting, Abnormal, Driving
Luo, Suspension, ElectricPowerSteering, DataDriven, Fatigue, Abnormal, Driving
Wang, Steering, suspension, DataDriven, Fatigue, Normal, Idling
Hu, SoundSystem, CVDP, ModelBased, Distraction, Abnormal, Driving
Zhang, Suspension, LithiumBattery, DataDriven, Happy, Normal, Idling
Zhang, Muffler, OBD, ModelBased, Distraction, Abnormal, Idling
Wang, AirConditinor, CVDP, ModelBased, AccelerationHabit, Normal, Idling
Chung, FanRadiator, suspension, ModelBased, Drowsiness, Normal, Driving
Lee, Steering, EPSG, ModelBased, MedicalCondition, Normal, Idling
Luo, Engine, suspension, ModelBased, Fatigue, Normal, Idling
Chung, Suspension, BGA, ModelBased, Mad, Abnormal, Driving
Beatrice, Radiator, LithiumBattery, ModelBased, Fatigue, Normal, Idling
Zhang, Steering, CVDP, DataDriven, MedicalCondition, Abnormal, Idling
Wang, Battery, suspension, DataDriven, Mad, Abnormal, Driving
Wang, AirConditinor, BGA, ModelBased, Mad, Abnormal, Driving
Wang, Brakes, BGA, ModelBased, Mad, Normal, Idling
Hu, Battery, LithiumBattery, ModelBased, Fatigue, Normal, Driving
Chung, Brakes, OBD, ModelBased, Drowsiness, Normal, Idling
Lee, Battery, OBD, DataDriven, Distraction, Abnormal, Idling
Hu, Battery, OBD, ModelBased, MedicalCondition, Normal, Idling
Zhang, Battery, BGA, ModelBased, AccelerationHabit, Normal, Driving
Zhang, Battery, ElectricPowerSteering, DataDriven, AccelerationHabit, Abnormal, Driving
Wang, Muffler, OBD, DataDriven, Drowsiness, Normal, Idling
Han, Muffler, suspension, ModelBased, Distraction, Normal, Driving
Beatrice, Muffler, EPSG, ModelBased, RoadRage, Abnormal, Idling
Zhang, Brakes, suspension, ModelBased, AccelerationHabit, Normal, Idling
Wang, Brakes, OBD, DataDriven, Distraction, Normal, Driving
Han, Radiator, AntiLockBrakes, ModelBased, Drowsiness, Abnormal, Driving
Han, Steering, AntiLockBrakes, DataDriven, Texting, Abnormal, Driving
Cesar, Radiator, CVDP, DataDriven, Distraction, Normal, Idling
Cesar, SoundSystem, LithiumBattery, ModelBased, RoadRage, Normal, Driving
Han, Battery, BGA, DataDriven, RoadRage, Normal, Idling
Chung, Muffler, OBD, DataDriven, Fatigue, Normal, Idling
Wang, Muffler, CVDP, DataDriven, AccelerationHabit, Abnormal, Driving
Luo, Suspension, suspension, ModelBased, Drowsiness, Abnormal, Driving
Zhang, Brakes, CVDP, DataDriven, Happy, Normal, Idling
Hu, Radiator, AntiLockBrakes, ModelBased, Fatigue, Abnormal, Idling
Lee, Steering, CVDP, DataDriven, Fatigue, Normal, Driving
Lee, Brakes, AntiLockBrakes, DataDriven, Drowsiness, Normal, Idling
Beatrice, Brakes, BGA, ModelBased, Fatigue, Abnormal, Idling
Hu, Engine, OBD, ModelBased, Happy, Abnormal, Idling
Han, Engine, LithiumBattery, DataDriven, AccelerationHabit, Abnormal, Idling
Han, Muffler, LithiumBattery, DataDriven, AccelerationHabit, Normal, Idling
Beatrice, Radiator, LithiumBattery, DataDriven, Fatigue, Abnormal, Driving
Cesar, Brakes, OBD, ModelBased, MedicalCondition, Normal, Idling
Lee, Engine, CVDP, ModelBased, Distraction, Abnormal, Driving
Luo, Battery, LithiumBattery, DataDriven, Fatigue, Normal, Idling
Beatrice, Steering, suspension, ModelBased, Texting, Abnormal, Idling
Cesar, Brakes, suspension, ModelBased, AccelerationHabit, Abnormal, Driving
Luo, Brakes, suspension, ModelBased, Drowsiness, Abnormal, Driving
Chung, FanRadiator, EPSG, DataDriven, MedicalCondition, Abnormal, Idling
Hu, FanRadiator, ElectricPowerSteering, ModelBased, AccelerationHabit, Normal, Driving
Hu, AirConditinor, LithiumBattery, DataDriven, Mad, Abnormal, Idling
Zhang, Battery, suspension, ModelBased, Happy, Abnormal, Idling
Wang, AirConditinor, CVDP, ModelBased, Distraction, Abnormal, Idling
Cesar, AirConditinor, CVDP, ModelBased, Happy, Abnormal, Idling
Hu, AirConditinor, BGA, ModelBased, Texting, Abnormal, Idling
Chung, Brakes, BGA, ModelBased, RoadRage, Abnormal, Driving
Luo, Engine, CVDP, DataDriven, Texting, Normal, Idling
Chung, FanRadiator, BGA, DataDriven, RoadRage, Abnormal, Idling
Chung, Radiator, LithiumBattery, ModelBased, Distraction, Normal, Idling
Hu, Brakes, ElectricPowerSteering, DataDriven, Drowsiness, Abnormal, Driving
Wang, Steering, AntiLockBrakes, ModelBased, Texting, Normal, Idling
Cesar, FanRadiator, OBD, ModelBased, MedicalCondition, Normal, Driving
Lee, Battery, ElectricPowerSteering, DataDriven, RoadRage, Abnormal, Driving
Wang, Muffler, suspension, ModelBased, Fatigue, Normal, Idling
Chung, Suspension, ElectricPowerSteering, DataDriven, Mad, Abnormal, Driving
Chung, FanRadiator, LithiumBattery, ModelBased, AccelerationHabit, Abnormal, Idling
Hu, Brakes, LithiumBattery, ModelBased, AccelerationHabit, Normal, Driving
Beatrice, Engine, LithiumBattery, ModelBased, RoadRage, Abnormal, Idling
Luo, FanRadiator, AntiLockBrakes, DataDriven, Drowsiness, Abnormal, Idling
Chung, Radiator, AntiLockBrakes, DataDriven, Texting, Abnormal, Driving
Luo, Suspension, BGA, ModelBased, Happy, Abnormal, Driving
Lee, AirConditinor, AntiLockBrakes, DataDriven, Happy, Normal, Idling
Cesar, Steering, ElectricPowerSteering, DataDriven, Happy, Abnormal, Idling
Beatrice, FanRadiator, ElectricPowerSteering, DataDriven, Happy, Normal, Driving
Chung, Suspension, suspension, ModelBased, AccelerationHabit, Normal, Idling
Cesar, Steering, LithiumBattery, DataDriven, Texting, Normal, Driving
Chung, Muffler, BGA, DataDriven, Texting, Abnormal, Driving
Wang, Suspension, EPSG, DataDriven, RoadRage, Abnormal, Idling
Chung, Suspension, EPSG, DataDriven, Fatigue, Abnormal, Driving
Lee, Battery, CVDP, ModelBased, RoadRage, Normal, Idling
Lee, AirConditinor, OBD, ModelBased, Texting, Normal, Driving
Chung, Brakes, ElectricPowerSteering, DataDriven, Texting, Normal, Idling
Wang, Battery, AntiLockBrakes, DataDriven, Distraction, Normal, Idling
Zhang, FanRadiator, LithiumBattery, ModelBased, RoadRage, Normal, Idling
Han, Battery, BGA, DataDriven, Mad, Normal, Idling
Hu, Engine, BGA, ModelBased, Mad, Abnormal, Driving
Hu, FanRadiator, EPSG, DataDriven, RoadRage, Normal, Driving
Luo, AirConditinor, CVDP, ModelBased, Distraction, Abnormal, Driving
Beatrice, Engine, LithiumBattery, DataDriven, Texting, Normal, Idling
Lee, Brakes, CVDP, DataDriven, Texting, Normal, Driving
Luo, Brakes, ElectricPowerSteering, DataDriven, Texting, Normal, Driving
Wang, FanRadiator, CVDP, DataDriven, Happy, Normal, Driving
Luo, Steering, OBD, ModelBased, Mad, Abnormal, Driving
Lee, Radiator, ElectricPowerSteering, DataDriven, Fatigue, Abnormal, Driving
Wang, Brakes, BGA, DataDriven, Happy, Normal, Driving
Wang, Battery, ElectricPowerSteering, ModelBased, RoadRage, Normal, Idling
Han, Steering, OBD, ModelBased, Drowsiness, Abnormal, Driving
Hu, Suspension, suspension, DataDriven, Happy, Abnormal, Idling
Cesar, FanRadiator, ElectricPowerSteering, ModelBased, Happy, Normal, Idling
Hu, Battery, ElectricPowerSteering, DataDriven, MedicalCondition, Normal, Idling
Han, AirConditinor, OBD, ModelBased, Texting, Normal, Driving
Hu, Radiator, AntiLockBrakes, DataDriven, Happy, Abnormal, Idling
Beatrice, Muffler, ElectricPowerSteering, ModelBased, Distraction, Normal, Driving
Lee, FanRadiator, BGA, ModelBased, Drowsiness, Normal, Idling
Hu, Engine, CVDP, ModelBased, Drowsiness, Abnormal, Idling
Hu, Muffler, AntiLockBrakes, DataDriven, Happy, Normal, Idling
Beatrice, Suspension, OBD, DataDriven, Distraction, Normal, Driving
Zhang, Steering, LithiumBattery, DataDriven, AccelerationHabit, Normal, Idling
Chung, Brakes, ElectricPowerSteering, DataDriven, Mad, Normal, Driving
Luo, Battery, AntiLockBrakes, ModelBased, RoadRage, Normal, Idling
Luo, AirConditinor, OBD, DataDriven, AccelerationHabit, Abnormal, Driving
Lee, Steering, BGA, DataDriven, Drowsiness, Abnormal, Driving
Hu, AirConditinor, LithiumBattery, DataDriven, AccelerationHabit, Normal, Idling
Chung, Suspension, suspension, ModelBased, Drowsiness, Abnormal, Driving
Chung, Brakes, ElectricPowerSteering, DataDriven, Mad, Abnormal, Idling
Zhang, FanRadiator, BGA, DataDriven, Mad, Abnormal, Idling
Cesar, Steering, suspension, ModelBased, Drowsiness, Normal, Driving
Lee, Radiator, EPSG, DataDriven, RoadRage, Abnormal, Driving
Wang, Muffler, LithiumBattery, ModelBased, Happy, Normal, Driving
Zhang, Suspension, ElectricPowerSteering, ModelBased, Fatigue, Normal, Idling
Beatrice, Battery, LithiumBattery, ModelBased, RoadRage, Normal, Idling
Zhang, Brakes, LithiumBattery, DataDriven, AccelerationHabit, Normal, Driving
Cesar, Radiator, BGA, ModelBased, Happy, Normal, Idling
Lee, Engine, LithiumBattery, DataDriven, Mad, Normal, Driving
Cesar, SoundSystem, suspension, DataDriven, Happy, Abnormal, Idling
Luo, Steering, BGA, DataDriven, RoadRage, Abnormal, Idling
Zhang, Engine, LithiumBattery, DataDriven, Mad, Abnormal, Driving
Hu, Muffler, AntiLockBrakes, DataDriven, Fatigue, Normal, Driving
Han, Steering, LithiumBattery, DataDriven, RoadRage, Normal, Idling
Cesar, Suspension, EPSG, ModelBased, AccelerationHabit, Abnormal, Idling
Lee, Radiator, EPSG, DataDriven, Mad, Abnormal, Idling
Lee, Engine, OBD, DataDriven, Happy, Abnormal, Idling
Chung, FanRadiator, BGA, ModelBased, RoadRage, Abnormal, Idling
Luo, Engine, CVDP, ModelBased, Mad, Abnormal, Driving
Zhang, Suspension, ElectricPowerSteering, DataDriven, RoadRage, Abnormal, Driving
Beatrice, Steering, suspension, ModelBased, RoadRage, Normal, Idling
Luo, Brakes, OBD, ModelBased, Texting, Normal, Idling
Beatrice, Muffler, CVDP, ModelBased, Happy, Normal, Idling
Cesar, Radiator, OBD, ModelBased, MedicalCondition, Abnormal, Idling
Wang, Brakes, AntiLockBrakes, DataDriven, Texting, Normal, Driving
Hu, Engine, suspension, DataDriven, Mad, Normal, Driving
Cesar, Muffler, OBD, ModelBased, Drowsiness, Normal, Idling
Zhang, Radiator, BGA, ModelBased, Texting, Abnormal, Idling
Lee, Brakes, suspension, ModelBased, Happy, Abnormal, Idling
Zhang, Steering, EPSG, DataDriven, Happy, Normal, Idling
Beatrice, Muffler, BGA, DataDriven, Distraction, Normal, Driving
Lee, FanRadiator, ElectricPowerSteering, ModelBased, Fatigue, Normal, Idling
Han, Brakes, suspension, ModelBased, Drowsiness, Abnormal, Idling
Beatrice, Brakes, suspension, ModelBased, Texting, Abnormal, Driving
Zhang, Steering, CVDP, ModelBased, Mad, Normal, Driving
Luo, Muffler, AntiLockBrakes, ModelBased, Mad, Abnormal, Idling
Beatrice, AirConditinor, EPSG, DataDriven, Mad, Normal, Driving
Chung, AirConditinor, suspension, ModelBased, Distraction, Normal, Idling
Beatrice, Muffler, CVDP, ModelBased, AccelerationHabit, Abnormal, Driving
Lee, Engine, ElectricPowerSteering, DataDriven, RoadRage, Abnormal, Idling
Hu, AirConditinor, CVDP, DataDriven, Happy, Normal, Driving
Cesar, Engine, LithiumBattery, ModelBased, Fatigue, Abnormal, Driving
Cesar, SoundSystem, BGA, DataDriven, Distraction, Normal, Idling
Luo, FanRadiator, CVDP, ModelBased, MedicalCondition, Normal, Idling
Chung, Engine, ElectricPowerSteering, DataDriven, Fatigue, Normal, Driving
Han, Steering, EPSG, ModelBased, MedicalCondition, Abnormal, Idling
Lee, Battery, AntiLockBrakes, ModelBased, Drowsiness, Normal, Driving
Beatrice, Battery, OBD, DataDriven, Distraction, Normal, Idling
Luo, Steering, OBD, ModelBased, Happy, Normal, Driving
Beatrice, SoundSystem, BGA, ModelBased, Mad, Abnormal, Driving
Lee, Battery, suspension, DataDriven, Distraction, Abnormal, Driving
Lee, Muffler, suspension, ModelBased, MedicalCondition, Abnormal, Driving
Hu, Steering, suspension, DataDriven, Fatigue, Abnormal, Driving
Wang, FanRadiator, suspension, ModelBased, Drowsiness, Normal, Idling
Beatrice, Battery, CVDP, ModelBased, AccelerationHabit, Normal, Driving
Wang, Muffler, EPSG, DataDriven, Distraction, Abnormal, Driving
Han, Muffler, ElectricPowerSteering, ModelBased, AccelerationHabit, Normal, Driving
Beatrice, Radiator, BGA, ModelBased, RoadRage, Normal, Idling
Luo, Engine, OBD, DataDriven, Fatigue, Abnormal, Idling
Luo, SoundSystem, CVDP, ModelBased, Texting, Normal, Driving
Lee, Radiator, EPSG, DataDriven, MedicalCondition, Abnormal, Idling
Zhang, Battery, CVDP, DataDriven, MedicalCondition, Normal, Driving
Beatrice, Brakes, ElectricPowerSteering, ModelBased, Mad, Abnormal, Driving
Lee, Suspension, ElectricPowerSteering, ModelBased, MedicalCondition, Normal, Driving
Lee, SoundSystem, BGA, DataDriven, Distraction, Abnormal, Idling
Hu, Suspension, BGA, ModelBased, Distraction, Normal, Idling
Han, SoundSystem, ElectricPowerSteering, ModelBased, Distraction, Abnormal, Driving
Chung, Steering, AntiLockBrakes, Da

Comment: I suppose you've got the basic idea right. But passing all your lists seems strained.